# Are there any integers a and b such that $a^2+b^2 = 10^{100}+3$

Tags: arithmetic

I try to find  integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2+b^2 = 10^{100}+3$, I try some number without any result

Comment: Note that $10^{100}+3\equiv3\pmod4$. Also note that a perfect square $\pmod4$ is either $0$ or $1$. What are the possibilities for $a^2+b^2\pmod4$?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

$a^2+b^2 $ is odd, so $ a$ and $ b $ have not the same parity.

Assume
$$a=2A \; \text{ and } \; b=2B+1$$

thus

$$4A^2+4B^2+4B=10^{100}+2$$
or

$$2A^2+2B^2+2B=5.10^{99}+1$$
the LHS is even, while the RHS is not.